# удаление некоторых id

Tags: mysql

здраствуйте, простой вопрос , не могу в гугле найти. Необходимо удалить города, оставить некоторые которые имеют id 60 id 50 и id 70, как удалить другие кроме этих, допустим с id 1 по id 350 но кроме вышеперечисленных

Comment: `DELETE  FROM your_table WHERE id NOT IN (60, 50, 70)`

Comment: Вам надо не ответ на конкретный вопрос в гугле искать, а например "Учебник SQL", потратьте день на его изучение (вообще достаточно нескольких часов) и ответы на такие простые вопросы будете знать сами

Answer (score 1):

В теории будет так:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id < 350 and id not in (60, 50, 70)
```

[in](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) - определяет набор для которых должно сработать условие

not - говорит, что как раз не нужно трогать то, что связано с набором в in.

Answer (score 0):

если у меня 2 ID (state_id и country_id) например, то как записать чтобы удалить из  geo_state все country_id кроме номера 53 например и 54

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]